# [Catalina]: GetMasterBlock: Error 1 opening /dev/rdisk2s2 during read-write mount

Tags: disk-utility, external-disk, mount, catalina

After upgrading to mac os catalina, I am unable to mount my external SSD drive in r/w mode. The external SSD drive is my time machine backup drive.

```
$   sudo mount -v -u -w  /dev/disk2s2 /Volumes/960GB_SSD

GetMasterBlock: Error 1 opening /dev/rdisk2s2
/dev/disk2s2 on /Volumes/960GB_SSD (hfs, local, journaled)
```

[image]
[image]
I had no such issue in Mojave before upgrading. Any pointers?

My laptop is a 2017 mac book pro.

Thanks.